# Oracle APEX - hidden regions flash on page refresh

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

On my page there are several region that are hidden or shown based on a condition.
I set a variable calculation before regions and then on change of that variable I show/hide various regions. Everything works as expected but I've noticed that when I refresh the page, for a split second I see the hidden regions flash and then disappear. Any way to fix that?

Comment: do you use "Dynamic Action" feature?

Comment: Yes, I have several dynamic actions on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that the DOM is rendered and once the page is loaded, the dynamic action fires. There is a brief moment between the page fully rendered and the dynamic action firing and that is when you see the component flash. All a dynamic action of type "Hide" does, is set the css style `display:none;` on the component.

A very simple workaround to prevent the flashing is to set "Custom Attributes" to `style=display:none;` for the region that should be hidden on page load. That way the component will not show but immediately be hidden.

[image]